# libcurl + visual studio problem when retrieving emails via IMAP, libcurl -d.dll not found

Tags: c++, c, curl, imap, libcurl

I get an error of "libcurl -d.dll not found" when running the following example program. Libcurl IS properly installed (visual studio can find the library and does not have any issues when running a different SMTP program.  I installed curl and curl[non-http] with vcpkg.  I did run "vcpkg integrate install". I checked for the susposidly missing file and it does exist inside of the vcpkg curl install folder.  When I copy that file to the c++ project folder it replaces that error with another one for a different missing file. When that file is also copied to the project folder the program compiles but does not work.
Any ideas how I can fix this?
I am using VS 2019 if that makes a difference. I did try reinstalling curl.

Please see code bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define USERNAME "email@gmail.com"

int GetMail(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    cout << "Enter password:\n";
    string User_PW;
    cin >> User_PW;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        /* Set username and password */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, USERNAME);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, User_PW);

        /* This will fetch message 1 from the user's inbox */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
            "imap://imap.gmail.com/Inbox/;UID=1");

        /* Perform the fetch */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* Always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return (int)res;
}

int main()
{
    GetMail();
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your compiler flags.  Please paste your build and link commands.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I am just using the default visual studio build flags run with [f5].  Please clarify?  I am somewhat new to programming.

Comment: So in order to build the program you are working on, VS 2019 is calling MSVC from the command lines with a bunch of arguments to tell it how to build the program.  I haven't used VS in a very long time, but these settings are generally under the build options  for the project.  There seems to be a random "-d" being passed, which is where the issue is. MSVC arguments start with "/" and gcc/llvm use "-."  I have a feeling something something in those build settings is not setup correctly.  BTW, there should be command-line output in the console of the IDE that will show you the entire command.

Comment: So... I could not find the settings for changing build flags. I did however create a new project and copied the exact same code into it and it works now... (I did not mess with settings for the previous project so I don't know why it works now...) The code still does not run though.  As soon as a password is entered it  seems to stop. I will try to figure out why. It is probably a problem with the code its self.

Comment: Nevermind previous comment.  Other problem was a result of an incorrect imap server parameters. If you want the rep copy and paste into an answer.